# Source controlling (git) docker-compose.yml

Tags: node.js, git, version-control, docker, docker-compose

My `docker-compose.yml` file orchestrates the containers for a PHP API based app and a Nodejs web frontend. Both of these are in seperate git repos.

Question: **Where and how should I check my `docker-compose.yml` file into git?**

My containers:

- Nginx
- Redis
- MySQL
- Nodejs App
- PHP App

Answer (score 1):

I think that I've accidentally answered to this question in other thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34001663/381939 (perhaps it is a partial answer)

Anyway, for a situation similar to yours, I have a separate repository for deployment related scripts and configuration. Also, I use [git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) for linking the application repositories into the deployment repo.

Comment: Can you elaborate more in your answer, perhaps with some directory / submodule structure examples. Otherwise very much a good answer!